# Outlook separates my table

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table

I wanted to do a newsletter with MailChimp and send it via Outlook.

I went through it like:

```html
<table style="width:49%;float:left">
        <tr>
            <th>Offerten
                <th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Akustik / Lärm:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16368: Anfrage des ASTRA für ein Detailprojekt Lärm (Einbau Schallschutzfenster) im Raum Lyssach
            </td>
        </tr>
            <th>Bauphysik:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16360: Neubau Turnhalle Minergie-P zertifiziert und Erweiterung Schule Plänke in Biel
    P16361: energetische und akustische Begleitung bei der Sanierung und Neubaus Mehrgene-rationenhaus in Zollikofen
    P16364: Neubau Wohnüberbauung Lohngasse in Bellmund
            </td>
        </tr>
                <th>Brandschutz:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16251.BR: Das Verfahren für die Vergabe der Marktüberwachungstätigkeit von Brandmeldern wurde vom BBL gestoppt. Das Pflichtenheft wird überarbeiten und wir werden neu eingeladen einzugeben.
    Voraussichtlich ab Mitte Oktober 2016
            </td>
        </tr>
                <th>UVB:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16335: Umbau Bhf Leissigen – Projekt der BLS
            </td>
        </tr>
                <th>Beweissicherung:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
    P16343: Rissaufnahmen von 10 Gebäuden inkl. Erschütterungsüberwachung in Bellach
            </td>
        </tr>
        
       <table style="width:49%; float:right">
        <tr>
            <th>Offres:
                <th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sols:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    P16351 : Expertise Sols-SDA Treycovagnes
    P16352 : Suivi pédologique de chantier pour la réfection d’infrastructures agricoles à Valbroye
    P16357 : Suivi pédologique de chantier pour la construction d’une nouvelle Landi à Cossonay
    P16373 : Expertise Sols-SDA à Chamblon
    P16375 : Expertise Sols-SDA à Pomy
            </td>
        </tr>

    <table style="width:49%;float:left">
        <tr>
            <th>Projekten
                <th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>AS:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16368: Anfrage des ASTRA für ein Detailprojekt Lärm (Einbau Schallschutzfenster) im Raum Lyssach
            </td>
        </tr>
            <th>Bauphysik:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16360: Neubau Turnhalle Minergie-P zertifiziert und Erweiterung Schule Plänke in Biel
    P16361: energetische und akustische Begleitung bei der Sanierung und Neubaus Mehrgene-rationenhaus in Zollikofen
    P16364: Neubau Wohnüberbauung Lohngasse in Bellmund
            </td>
        </tr>
                <th>Brandschutz:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P16251.BR: Das Verfahren für die Vergabe der Marktüberwachungstätigkeit von Brandmeldern wurde vom BBL gestoppt. Das Pflichtenheft wird überarbeiten und wir werden neu eingeladen einzugeben.
    Voraussichtlich ab Mitte Oktober 2016
            </td>
        </tr>
                <th>Natürliche Lebensraüme:</th>
        </tr>
        
          <table style="width:49%;float:right">
        <tr>
            <th>Projets:
                <th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sols:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    P16351: Expertise Sols-SDA Treycovagnes
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Bruit:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    P16366 : Bruit de chantier 24h/24 – STEP Lausanne
    P16337 : Bruit de ventilation intérieure – HEIG-VD
    P16339 : Bruit Routier – Valangin - Routes Cantonales
    P15185 : Exposition publique Gabarit sonore éolien
            </td>
        </tr>
```

But my table doesn't got 2 raws, it puts it under and I don't know what to do, help please?

I have to send it tomorrow.. so stressed and don't know what to do..

[image]
[image]

Comment: float:left is not supported.

Comment: So how could I do it please?

Comment: Instead of taking 2 table use td.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken several **th** in your code. Also correct that and structure your data in below format.

Refer this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvhcc1q3/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:25%;" valign="top">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        //1st table data
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" valign="top">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        //2nd table data
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" valign="top">
      <table style="width:100%;">
         // 3rd table data
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" valign="top">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        //4th table data
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx <3
But the "Offres" table show's like it's at 25% on oulook even if I put it in 50%, got a solution?